# Side effects of lowering minimum processor state under power options to 5% for AMD Ryzen CPU

Tags: cpu, power-consumption, amd-ryzen, powersave

I recently switched from Intel CPU to AMD Ryzen 7 2700x CPU. For Intel CPU, under "power options"->"processor power management"->"minimum processor state", the default is 5%. For AMD using the "AMD Ryzen Balanced" power plan, the default is 90%.

I am puzzled why AMD wants to use such a high minimum processor state. Wouldn't this waste power? I set it down to 5%. So far, the PC works fine. There should be some reasons why AMD set 90% as default. However, I am not sure what are the side effects and risks.

I would like to ask what are the side effects and risks of changing from the default 90% to 5%?

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Robert Hallock (AMD's Technical Marketing) commented [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/a9q96u/is_the_ryzen_balanced_power_plan_still_relevant/eclsig7/) on reddit:

"4) Now that Ryzen Balanced and OEM Balanced both disable Core Parking, the need for Ryzen Balanced is diminished. 99% of the time, these plans will offer equal performance.

4a) However, the Ryzen Balanced plan still sets a minimum clockspeed of 90% on a core that is actively under load. This eliminates some small latency penalties that occur when ramping a CPU from low clock to high clock. This will give the Ryzen Balanced plan a small edge in select cases. It's a few percent, and I've only seen it measured in synthetic workloads."

And a [benchmark](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/9xof97/ryzen_2nd_gen_windows_power_plans_benchmarks/) posted on reddit by user *Intricate081* shows that Ryzen Balanced with its 90% minimum processor state, has a minimial performance gain compared with the default Windows Balanced (5% minimum), but with increased idle temperatures and power consumption.